# Determine web app path

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Tool Suite (really eclipse). I just created a new springMVC project and created a simple controller. There was a problem with how STS created the project so I had to manually fix the groupID and artifactID in the pom. The problem I am currently having is I can't seem to hit my tomcat server (published and launched by STS). I have checked the directory structure in tomcat where it gets published and everything seems to be fine but I get 404's when I try and hit the controller. The tomcat logs look as if nothing has even tried to connect to it. They also show that my controller has been mapped:

```
2013-10-14 09:09:17.763] INFO  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/Login],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.verisk.underwriting.ims.web.IMSController.test()
```

This is what my controller looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("Login")
public class IMSController
{
    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String test()
    {
        return "SUCCESS";
    }
}
```

The app is called ims, so I should be able to hit this controller with this request:

```
http://localhost/ims/Login
```

It is configured with a java config (AppConfig.java):

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.some.package.ims.web")
    public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
    {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
        {
             registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");  
        }
    }
```

Is there a config file that specifies the base path for the app?

Answer (score 0):

`http://localhost/ims/Login` will hit port `80` ; by default tomcat runs on port `8080`. So unless you have changed tomcat's HTTP port to `80` you need to use `localhost:8080`

If the port is good then check that your application context path is really `ims`, by default it is the exact name of the generated `WAR` file. If you use WTP, eclipse "servers" view will show it under the server instance.

If the context path is good then check the configured URL mapping in your `web.xml` descriptor. Make sure you are not missing a prefix in the URL for REST/MVC servlet URL aggregation. In your case it looks like you should use `.../resources/Login` because your configured your resources to be under the `/resources/**` pattern.

Comment: where can i find the application context path?

Comment: Still no good and my tomcat logs are unchanged. Usually if I hit a bad url it will say something along the lines of "no mapping found for..." (assuming I hit the right app path)

Comment: The context path is by default the name of the war file. How do you deploy your application on tomcat?

Comment: It's just a maven project that gets built and deployed by eclipse.

Comment: Then it should be the name of the eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `.metadata` directory of our workspace. It has a `.plugins` folder, that constains the `org.eclipse.wst.server.core` directory, and there is one (or more) `tmp0` diectory. That contains a `wtpwebapps` directory. This contains the deployed webapps with the name that is used -- for example `MyApp`.

```
<Workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyApp
```

Then your Login page is located at

```
http://localhost[:8080]/MyApp/Login
```

Comment: This is from the specified file:
org.eclipse.jst.jee.server\:ims=C\:\\Tomcat7\\wtpwebapps\\ims

and I am configure to run tomcat on port 80 which works for my other apps.